# Correct position of equal sign in multiline equation

Tags: notation

An equation on a piece of paper is too long for a single line and needs to be split into two lines. The equal sign happens to be at the line break.

Does the equal sign belong at the end of the first line, or the beginning of the second line?

Comment: I don't know if there's a hard and fast rule for this, but a quick look at the math in this very website will show you most of the time, the equals sign goes at the start of the second line.

Comment: I think the equals sign will be more conspicuous if you put it at the beginning of the second line (with some white space to its left). If you can, it could be better to use auxiliary definitions to abbreviate your equation so it fits on one line.